# When you run a Python script with `sudo`, run only certain parts with `sudo`?

Tags: python, sudo

I'm running a script as `sudo script.py`. However, I only need to run certain parts as root. So, is it possible to drop capabilities by default, then run certain parts as root?

All the parts that need root are subprocesses `eg. subprocess.Popen(["sudo","ls"])`

Comment: It's a one-way street.  If you start as `sudo`, you can release the privilege, but once released you cannot get it back.

Comment: ...what you _can_ do is fork off a subprocess, drop privileges there, and communicate between the process-as-root and the process-as-an-unprivileged-user. Of course, there's a lot of security risk if that communication is done _badly_; it's much safer to use a pipe than a TCP socket, f/e. But going into details on doing it well is generally too broad a topic to be a good question here, unless you've made an attempt and hit a specific problem?

Comment: What does the script do? If it's mostly doing shell-type stuff, it might be easier to rewrite it as a shell script, or at least write a wrapper shell script. I say this cause I've never needed to de-elevate a Python script, but I know [it's easy to do in shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/978467/301745). BTW, [you can use the environment variable `SUDO_USER` to get the name of the sudoer](https://askubuntu.com/a/866573/301745).

Comment: Updated (all parts that need sudo are simple commands).